# In node-red-dashboard, how to add md-icon in an md-button

Tags: angularjs, node-red

I am new to node-red, dashboard, AngularJS, and the built in icons that come with the node-red dashboard so please show mercy. I would like to make my own buttons with icons so I am using the dashboard template node. Modifying the example in the info, I am doing this:

```
<script>
  var value = "hello world";
  this.scope.action = function() { return value; }
</script>
<md-button ng-click="send({payload:action()})">
  <md-icon class="material-icons">refresh</md-icon>
  Refresh
</md-button>
```

I am sure I am missing something very simple. I just want the circular arrow icon to appear before the Refresh text. Can anyone give me some quick guidance here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and had to look at the dashboard source code to figure it out. We need to use `<ui-icon>`. This should work for you:

```
<script>
  var value = "hello world";
  this.scope.action = function() { return value; }
</script>
<md-button ng-click="send({payload:action()})">
  <ui-icon icon="refresh"></ui-icon>
  Refresh
</md-button>
```

Edit: Link to button source: https://github.com/node-red/node-red-dashboard/blob/master/src/components/ui-component/templates/button.html